# Would balefire obey gravity?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, magical-theory

In addition to the other logistical balefire questions, I was wondering if balefire obeys the laws of gravity.  It is described as a bar of liquid fire, but I always thought of it as more like a laser.  If I shot balefire into the sky, would it fall back down (I could try this, of course, but I am sort of scared.)

Comment: weavings dont obey the laws of gravity in general.

Comment: @Himarm Drat, [beat me to it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27787273#27787273).

Comment: @randal'thor Why don't you just try it out?  Give us something firsthand?

Comment: @CHEESE Confirmed: I just sent a bar of balefire up into the sky, and it kept on going until I released the weave. Lews Therin tells me that weaves of the One Power aren't material objects but are made of something 'other' and therefore not subject to physical laws.

Comment: @randal'thor  Awesome, thanks.  I knew you would be able to save yourself if it came back down, I myself am rather weak in the Power.

Answer (score 3):

The majority of Weavings we see in the book go straight in which ever way thrown until they hit an object, or the weaving's dissipate. Other then say causing rain to fall, which is more the act of causing weather patterns I have noticed 0 draw of gravity upon weavings.

Weaves are consciously maintained, or tied off if applicable in which case they continue their function as is for an extended period of time.

so unless you forced your weaving of balefire to return to you, you are at no chance of it accidentally striking yourself.

Balefire also seems to only work in straight lines, as its used in fights in which changing its direction slightly would hit the target but instead second weaves are sent out instead.